# Registering complex scala classes with Kryo in spark-shell and Scala jars

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, serialization, kryo

I have a new spark 2.3.1 application...  it ran fine for a while, but now it's broken as data volume has increased.

The orginal error is a kryo serialization problem...  `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException` at failure.  The weirdest part is that it's not consistent...  if I run identical code, on identical data, on my non-shared cluster, it may or may not fail and seems totally random.

I've increased `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max` up to `2047m` (the max) from `256m` (my default) just to see what happens, and it sill fails with the same error.  I've also tried increasing the parallelism in RDD's that fail (6x per executor from 3x), and no luck.

Now I'm trying to run code snippets in `spark-shell --conf spark.kryo.registrationRequired=true` to find all the classes I need to register to shrink the size when serializing, and then incrementally adding them to the `--conf 'spark.kryo.classesToRegister=org.myOrg.MyClass1,org.myOrg.MyClass2'` and will later move them into the jar (`conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[MyClass1], classOf[MyClass2]))`) after I've found them all (there's way more than I expected).

**There's one that I absolutely cannot figure out how to register though.**  The error looks like this...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: org.myOrg.MyClass[]
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(org.myOrg.MyClass[].class);
```

I suspect it's an argument `Iterable[MyClass]` for some other class like `class MyOuterClass(val mcs: Iterable[MyClass])` but everything I try to register fails to work.  I believe `MyClass[]` is a `java.lang.Array[MyClass]` but I've tried registering every combination of `Array`, `Iterable`, `[]`, etc. that I can think of, and no luck getting it registered.

Any advice for the syntax to register `Iterable`, `List`, `TupleN` in both the command line launch of spark-shell and ultimately in the code?  Ultimately I'll have some very nested tuples as well, but I haven't gotten that far yet.

The closest result I can find in stackoverflow is here, but I can't get make this work for me either.  [Require kryo serialization in Spark (Scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394140/require-kryo-serialization-in-spark-scala)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify...  after successfully registering `MyClass` I still get an error message `Class is not registered: MyClass[]` and I can't figure out what the `[]` are at the end or how to register to make those go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you class name is `MyClass` then try registering with `[LMyClass;`

`conf.registerKryoClasses(Array( Class.forName("[LMyClass;")))`

it should load and register array class for `MyClass`

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I can successfully register most classes using `Array(classOf[MyClass], ...)` and it works fine.  But with `MyClass` successfully registered, I still get an error msg `Class is not registered: MyClass[]` and I can't figure out what the `[]` at the end is indicating or how to fix.

Comment: also, what's the difference between registering using `classOf[MyClass]` and `Class.forName("[LMyClass;")`?  I've never seen that notation before.

Comment: This works!!  Thank you!!  I see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) that java class names for arrays have that format like you gave `"[LName;"` but I don't really understand what `Class.forName("[LMyClass;")` is doing different from `classOf[MyClass]`.  Any clarification appreciated, but thankful for the answer either way.